# php array_intersect associative and indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I check if keys are set in an array without using multiple isset(...)

I thought of something like:

```
$arr1 = [
"keyA" => 1,
"keyB" => 2,
"keyC" => 3
];

$arr2 = ['keyB', 'keyD'];

$anyExists = empty(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

This should evaluate to true if any item of `$arr2` is a key of `$arr1`.
It obviously does not work. But is there a similarly nice solution without using loops?

Comment: You want if ANY exist or ALL exist?

Comment: 1) You want `array_intersect_key()` 2) In your second array think what is the key and what is the value

Comment: @AbraCadaver it should check if any exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want to get the keys as values from the first array as it checks values and not keys, and you want `!empty()` to return `true` if it's NOT empty and `false` if it IS empty:

```
$anyExists = !empty(array_intersect(array_keys($arr1), $arr2));
```

You could use `array_intersect_key()`, but then you would need to flip the second array to get the values as keys:

```
$anyExists = !empty(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)));
```

Or define your array as:

```
$arr2 = ['keyB' => true, 'keyD' => true];
```

Comment: I will use `array_keys` instead of `array_flip` and eventually `array_flip` to build `$arr2` in the `array_intersect_key` version.

Comment: array_intersect_key & flipping the second array is a great solution for my case

Comment: flipping the first does not work if the values are strings

Comment: array_keys ... even better :)

Comment: Yes array keys is better because flipping with duplicate values would eliminate duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

I find disallowing multiple `isset()` calls to be an unfortunate requirement because it is sure to be the faster option. Additionally, by writing the calls into a loop with a conditional `break` or `return` will improve its efficiency again.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UG6nt))

```
function anyKeyExists($haystack, $needles) {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (isset($haystack[$needle])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$array = [
    "keyA" => 1,
    "keyB" => 2,
    "keyC" => 3
];

echo "noMatch: " , (int)anyKeyExists($array, ['keyD', 'keyF']) , "\n";
echo "oneMatch: " , anyKeyExists($array, ['keyB', 'keyD']) , "\n";
echo "twoMatches: " , anyKeyExists($array, ['keyA', 'keyC']) , "\n";
```

Output:

```
noMatch: 0
oneMatch: 1
twoMatches: 1
```

If you *must* use functional programming, you can avoid the `empty()` call after intersecting the keys by merely casting the output array as a boolean using `!!` or `(bool)`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Hvn9S))

```
$array = [
    "keyA" => 1,
    "keyB" => 2,
    "keyC" => 3
];

echo "noMatch: " , (int)!!array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(['keyD', 'keyF'])) , "\n";
echo "oneMatch: " , !!array_intersect_key($array, array_flip( ['keyB', 'keyD'])) , "\n";
echo "twoMatches: " , !!array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(['keyA', 'keyC'])) , "\n";
```

(Same output as previous snippet)

P.s. It should be obvious, but in case it is not, I'll explain that my techniques are returning `true` or `false` evaluations.  I am casting the `false` outcomes as `(int)` so that they are expressed as `0` values instead of empty strings.  `true`, when echoed, is represented as a `1`.

Comment: If the mark has come from a justice seeking moderator, please open a private chat, because this hurts Stack Overflow more than me.